# Can saving a model fail after pre_save?

Tags: django, django-signals

I have a `pre_save` signal set up for my `User` model that does something before a `User` is saved. My question is, will a `User.save()` function ever fail after the `pre_save` has already been executed? Basically I'm doing something in the `pre_save` that I wouldn't want to do if the `User.save()` fails. Should I be worried about this corner case?

**NOTE:** I cannot use `post_save` because I need the `pre_save` `instance` object.

Comment: I think if you will use `with transaction.atomic()` it will not do any harm.